# How to load one certain js before all others?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

We are struggling around here with SVG in IE8. Amongst other approaches we'ld also like to try the [SVG Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). In it's [quick start guide](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/docs/QuickStart.html) they say:

> To use SVG Web, you must drop a script tag into your HTML page. This *must* be the first script tag on your page.

The JS is now loaded by a custom module. I tried

```
drupal_add_js($modulepath . '/libraries/svg.js', array(
   'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
   'weight' => -1000,
   'every_page' => TRUE));
```

When I vary these options it's sometimes higher, sometimes lower. The above code makes it the highest I can get it. But there still are quite a number of scripts loaded prior to it.

How can we ensure the svg.js to load first? Is there maybe a way to do it with `drupal_add_js` in our custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [js_injector module](https://drupal.org/project/js_injector) in which you can choose the priority of your .js file